# How to address my executable file inside ".config/openbox/autostart"

Tags: ubuntu, root, kiosk, openbox

I have compiled my code in this path : `/home/m/ChatScript-master/SRC` and created executable file `myapp` .

I can run it from inside the `SRC` folder like `./myapp`. But when I try `/home/m/ChatScript-master/SRC/myapp` from my `/home/m` it gives me:

```
   in cs_init.txt at 0: 
    Error opening utf8writeappend file LOGS/startlog.txt: No such file or directory
```

Why do I get this error message?

My main problem is that, I want to build a kiosk like system and want to add my executable file inside : `/home/m/.config/openbox/autostart` like this:

```
$ cat /home/m/.config/openbox/autostart 
echo 7 > /tmp/yy
/home/m/ChatScript-master/SRC/myapp &
echo 8 > /tmp/yy2
```

But it doesn't work!
I could do it already with other programs, but this program gives me this error!

NOTE: There are some folders inside `ChatScript-master` directory like `SRC` and `LOGS` and my executable file is inside `SRC` folder.

Comment: `LOGS/startlog.txt` isn't available from your working directory whenever you get that error (and almost certainly not when you autostart your program).

Comment: @StephenNewell: isn't a way to tell the program start the `app` from that directory?

Comment: Yes; `cd` to it explicitly before executing.

Comment: @StephenNewell: I tried this but didn't work:  `( cd /home/m/ChatScript-master/SRC && ./myapp ) &`